# Dynamically update the layout of Recyclerview item without changing scroll position

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Scenario :
I have a Card List, basically a RecyclerView, there are only two items in the Recycler view.I am also extending RecyclerView.LayoutManager() and overriding the onLayoutChildren() method of LayoutManager class.
Initially the second card is at bottom, and when I swipe up, the second card scrolls to the top, just a little below the first card.

On click of the Generate Barcode Button in the second card (second item in the list), I hide the button and display the barcode image replacing the buton. Upon updating the card layout, the onLayoutChildren() method is called automatically. This method is overriden to display the cards at specific position on startup of recycler view. This causes the Layout Manager to redraw the children views. Hence, the second card is scrolling back to the initial position.

Expected Behaviour: The second card should not scroll down, when we try to update the second card layout.

StackCardLayoutManager.kt

```
class StackCardLayoutManager(
    private val maxItemCount: Int
) : RecyclerView.LayoutManager() {
private val addedChildren: List<View>
    get() = (0 until childCount).map { getChildAt(it) ?: throw NullPointerException() }
private var firstTime: Boolean = true

init {
    Log.d(TAG_K, "StackCardLayoutManager.init()")
}

override fun generateDefaultLayoutParams(): RecyclerView.LayoutParams =
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)

override fun isAutoMeasureEnabled(): Boolean = true

override fun onLayoutChildren(
        recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler,
        state: RecyclerView.State
) {
    Log.d(TAG_K, "StackCardLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(itemcount : ${state.itemCount}) addedChildren Size : ${addedChildren.size} firstTime : $firstTime")
    firstTime = false
    if (state.itemCount == 0) {
        return
    }

    if (state.itemCount > maxItemCount) {
        throw RuntimeException("Can not set more Item than $maxItemCount")
    }
    detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler)

    for (i in 0 until state.itemCount) {
        Log.d(TAG_K, "StackCardLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren($i) - layoutDecorated")
        val view = recycler.getViewForPosition(i)
        measureChild(view, 0, 0)
        addView(view)
        val layoutParams = view.layoutParams as RecyclerView.LayoutParams
        val left = layoutParams.marginStart
        Log.d(TAG_K, "StackCardLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren() left  : $left")
        val top = (view.measuredHeight * i * 1.15).toInt()
        Log.d(TAG_K, "StackCardLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren() top  : $top")
        val right = view.measuredWidth + layoutParams.marginEnd
        Log.d(TAG_K, "StackCardLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren() right  : $right")
        val bottom = top + view.measuredHeight
        Log.d(TAG_K, "StackCardLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren() bottom  : $bottom")
        layoutDecorated(view, left, top, right, bottom)
        view.setTag(InitializedPosition.TOP.key, top)
    }
}

override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean = true

override fun scrollVerticallyBy(
        dy: Int,
        recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler,
        state: RecyclerView.State
): Int = dy.also { deltaY ->
    Log.d("stackcardlayout", "scrollVerticallyBy: $deltaY")
    if (childCount == 0) {
        Log.d("stackcardlayout", "scrollVerticallyBy: child count is 0")
        return@also
    }
    var deltaY1 = 0
    addedChildren.forEachIndexed { index, view ->
        val initializedTop = view.getTag(InitializedPosition.TOP.key) as Int
        val layoutParams = view.layoutParams as RecyclerView.LayoutParams
        val left = layoutParams.marginStart

        if(deltaY < 0){
            deltaY1 = -500
        }else {
            deltaY1 = 500
        }

        val top = min(max((view.top - deltaY1), index * dpToPx(70)), initializedTop)
        val right = view.measuredWidth + layoutParams.marginEnd
        val bottom = top + view.measuredHeight
        layoutDecorated(view, left, top, right, bottom)
    }
}

private enum class InitializedPosition(val key: Int) {
    TOP(R.integer.top)
}
}
```

I have tried to google around this solution and found similar issue on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721607/android-recyclerview-layoutmanagers-onlayoutchildren-called-when-item-content-i), but that solution is not valid for androidx Recyclerview, but valid only for android v7 Recycyler view support library.

Answer (score 0):

I see the answer. it is suggested you to according to the `eatRequestLayout()`
method to realize your custom view `requestLayout` method.

```
// RecyclerView requestlayout
@Override
    public void requestLayout() {
        if (!mEatRequestLayout) {
            super.requestLayout();
        } else {
            mLayoutRequestEaten = true;
        }
    }
//RecyclerView.eatRequestLayout
void eatRequestLayout() {
        if (!mEatRequestLayout) {
            mEatRequestLayout = true;
            mLayoutRequestEaten = false;
        }
    }
```

because of the `requestLayout` as the document says, the view re-draw according to it

### Call this when something has changed which has invalidated the layout of this view. This will schedule a layout pass of the view tree.

in your custom view `requestLayout`, you can according your situation, to set a different flag to prevent the re-draw.